# how to use animxyz.css to animate fade-in from right on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this CSS lib https://animxyz.com/

**How to make this card fade in from right on hover?**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@animxyz/core@0.3.0/dist/animxyz.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;margin:1rem">

  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your title and the message are different. On hover or after the page is loaded?

Comment: As far as I see there is no "built-in utility". But you can just copy the fade-in properties to hover.